# Regex in Python (30 M)

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I have the following text :

```
Adam, 30 M, Husband
```

Expected Output :

```
Adam, 30, M, Husband,
```

My Approach :

```
re.sub(r'\b(\d{1,2}\s\w{1},)\b', r'\1,', text)
```

How can I get a comma between 30 and M as shown in the output above?

Comment: Check out this tool: https://regex101.com/ Any time I need to build with regex, I use this to help the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> s = 'Adam, 30 M, Husband'
>>> re.sub(r'(?is)(\d+)(\s)', '\\1, ', s)
'Adam, 30, M, Husband'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
([\S\d]+)[\,\s]+
```

and replace by: \1,